# Camel @Header annotation not working when using spring ProxyFactory

Tags: spring, proxy, apache-camel, interceptor

When I use the camel @Header annotation in an interface, and call the bean (that implements it) directly, the Header value is filled. But when I proxy it with the spring ProxyFactoryBean then the @Header annotated parameter is empty. Probably I'm doing something wrong or am missing part of the configuration.

```java
public interface Foo {
   public void execute(@Header("FooHeader") String headerValue);
}

public class FooImpl implements Foo {
   public void execute(String headerValue) {
      System.out.println(headerValue);
   }
}

public class FooInterceptor implements org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor {
    public Object invoke(final MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
        return invocation.proceed();
    }
}
```

spring context:

```xml
<bean id="foo" class="FooImpl"/>
<bean id="fooInterceptor" class="FooInterceptor"/>

<bean id="fooProxy" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="target" ref="foo"/>
    <property name="interfaces">
        <list>              
            <value>Foo</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="interceptorNames">
        <list>
            <value>fooInterceptor</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The camel route DSL:

```
from("foo-queue").to("bean:foo?method=execute");
```

prints the value of the header, but the route:

```
from("foo-queue").to("bean:fooProxy?method=execute");
```

prints `null`. Seems that in my setup, camel does not "see" the header annotation that's on the interface, that the proxy implements.

So, how can I make camel see the annotation and inject the value of the header as an argument to the method?

Answer (score 0):

`ProxyFactoryBean` is a spring and not Camel, and as such it does not know about those Camel annotations.

Instead see here how to use Camel Proxy in Spring XML files: http://camel.apache.org/using-camelproxy.html

Comment: Hi Claus, thank you for your answer. If I understand camel proxy correctly I have to implement the interface. The problem is that I want to proxy several services by adding some functionality (in this case, custom object locking). I want to prevent having to implement many interfaces, therefore I tried the spring proxying/interceptor strategy. I'm trying to understand why camel DOES know what to do if my own class implements the interface, but does NOT see the annotation if a dynamic proxy does. The method it needs to call has the exact same interface method signature, with @Header annotation.